# Filled plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of points like this:

```
x_axis = np.arange(0, 100)
```

and

```
y_axis = np.zeros(100)
y_axis[17 : 23] = 1.
```

Now, I am plotting this data with the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(50,1))
plt.fill_between(x_axis, 0, y_axis, color='blue', alpha=.25)
```

But I am getting the following image:

[image]

As the `fill_between` expects corner of a polygon this is expected. I want to plot a filled square between `17` to `23`.  How do I achieve this instead of a trapezium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is step argument helping you ? You can set it to "pre" or  "post".

```
plt.fill_between(x_axis, 0, y_axis, color='blue', alpha=.25, step="pre")
```